# Filter array and return object by unique ID and get First and Last Index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array Like this:

```
[{
    "res": [ '123', 'One', '20210318' ]
}, {
    "res": [ '123', 'One', '20210319' ]
}, {
    "res": [ '123', 'One', '20210320' ]
}, {
    "res": [ '123', 'One', '20210321' ]
},{
    "res": [ '456', 'Two', '20210401' ]
},{
    "res": [ '456', 'Two', '20210402' ]
},{
    "res": [ '456', 'Two', '20210403' ]
},{
    "res": [ '456', 'Two', '20210404' ]
}]
```

I am trying to get

```
[{ 
    "res": [ '123', 'One', '20210318' ]
 }, {
    "res": [ '123', 'One', '20210321' ]
 },{
    "res": [ '456', 'Two', '20210401' ]
    },{
    "res": [ '456', 'Two', '20210404' ]
}]
```

which "One" has the first unique value "20210318" and last index unique value "20210321"
and "Two" which has the first unique value "20210401" and last index unique value "20210404"

I have just managed to filter the array by their unique IDs
and I'm getting only the two results which is the first unique "One" and first unique "Two"

```
  const getFilteredArray = array.filter((v,i,a)=> {

    const getFilter = a.findIndex( t => {
      return t.res[0] === v.res[0]
    }) === i;

    return getFilter;
  })
```

Comment: Group them by id (you will find plenty of similar questions on SO), sort them in whatever way is suitable, grab the first and last element for every group.

Comment: It the correlation between the first element (e.g. `'123'`) and the second one (e.g. `'One'`) always granted and unique (e.g. you cannot have a `['123', 'Three', ...]`)? Is it always going to be the case that the last item is sorted as in your example code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, maybe not the best solution

```
const grouped = array.reduce((acc, {res: [k1, k2, val]}) => {
    acc[k2] = acc[k2] || {};
    acc[k2].k1 = k1
    if(acc[k2].min == null || acc[k2].min > val) acc[k2].min = val;
    if(acc[k2].max == null || acc[k2].max < val) acc[k2].max = val;
    return acc;
}, {})
Object.keys(grouped).reduce((acc, k) => {
    const v = grouped[k];
    acc.push({res: [v.k1, k, v.min]});
    acc.push({res: [v.k1, k, v.max]});
    return acc;
}, []);
```